# matplotlib, How to save subplot with scrollbar

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hi I searched nice module to save subplot with scrollbar. but this module can only show plot not save file showing with 'Segmentation fault (core dumped)' message...

I don't know why.. Can you help me..? Actually when I saved only one plot, It was working well. but When I saved multiple plot with for loop function, that message show and block script running..

```python````

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from PyQt4 import QtGui
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
    class ScrollableWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
     def __init__(self, fig, savefile):
    self.qapp = QtGui.QApplication([])
    QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
    self.widget = QtGui.QWidget()
    self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)
    self.widget.setLayout(QtGui.QVBoxLayout())
    self.widget.layout().setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
    self.widget.layout().setSpacing(0)

    self.fig = fig
    self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.fig)
    self.canvas.draw()
    self.scroll = QtGui.QScrollArea(self.widget)
    self.scroll.setWidget(self.canvas)

    self.nav = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self.widget)
    self.widget.layout().addWidget(self.nav)
    self.widget.layout().addWidget(self.scroll)
    #self.show()
    plt.savefig(savefile)
    #exit() 
    #exit(self.qapp.exec_()) 

    # create a figure and some subplots
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=4, nrows=5, figsize=(16,16))
    for ax in axes.flatten():
      ax.plot([2,3,5,1])

 # pass the figure to the custom window
 a = ScrollableWindow(fig,'test.png')
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59349631/save-a-matplotlib-figure-from-inside-pyqt-class

Comment: Wait, did you ignore my comment on your previous question?